# Blazor MAUI - SQL Server not connecting

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, blazor, database-connection, maui

I am building a Blazor MAUI app which I am attempting to connect to my SQL Server. I am using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and a connection string which was generated by my Visual Studio.

In order to generate my connection string, I opened Views > Server Explorer in Visual Studio to add a data connection. I successfully connected to my database which added it to my Server Explorer panel. When viewing its properties, I can see a connection string containing the details of how I connected to my database: `Data Source=192.168.1.50;Initial Catalog=MYDB;User ID=sa;Password=********`.

From here, I have been trying to use this connection string in a static class to connect to my database. So far, my class looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyApp.Services
{
    public static class SqlServer
    {
        public static void Query()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Process started");
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.1.50;Initial Catalog=MYDB;User ID=sa;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(connection.ConnectionString);
                connection.Open();
                Debug.WriteLine("Connection success");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I call this method with `SqlServer.Query();` in a razor page, at the start of my `OnInitializedAsync()` method. When the page loads, my debug window prints "Process started", then the connection string, but always fails on `connection.Open();`. I always get this error: `Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll`. I am not sure what to do from here--I know the details of my connection string are correct, since I use them to login to my database just fine. I am using a static class to handle the connection because that's what the examples show in the [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0). Maybe I need to take a different route altogether?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: use a try catch and see what the error message is

Answer (score 0):

I used a try catch as suggested, like this:

```
try { connection.Open(); }
catch (Exception e) { Debug.WriteLine(e); }
```

And got this SSL trust error here: [Microsoft SQL Server: SSL Provider, error: 0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/error-message-when-you-connect)

To fix the issue, I just added this to my connection string: `Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;`. The connection is working just fine now.

Comment: I suggest writing `e.Message` might be more helpful.